# Data-only sim-card for a 1-week stay in Hungary

Tags: budget, cellphones, data-plans, hungary

Preparing for my trip to Sziget, I was wondering what the cheapest prepaid data sim cards would be Hungary has to offer. I checked the [Prepaid Data Sim Wikia](http://prepaid-data-sim-card.wikia.com/wiki/Hungary) and was planning on buying Magyar Telekom's *Domino Quick* starter pack with 1290HUF (~4 euro) credit on it to get the *Netplusz L* data package for 1GB, which should be sufficient for a week. Or might there be a better deal out there I could make use of?

On a side note, we would be coming from Belgium, driving through Germany, Czech Republic, Poland, Slovakia and Austria. So unless someone could offer a better alternative that could be used in all countries, we would just wait and get the Hungarian sim card.

Comment: are you specifically looking for sim cards? if you are anything like me and have huge data requirements and lots of devices, I often look for mobile wifi hotspots http://www.vodafone.hu/eng/internet/pocket-wifi

Comment: @EdmundYeung99 It all depends on the price, but I prefer not to have such a hotspot. It would be cumbersome to carry around an additional device, when every phone can work as a wifi hotspot just the same. My phone can connect 8 devices and has higher speeds than those hotspots, so I prefer a sim-card unless those hotspots are considerably cheaper.

Comment: Note that starting in [June 2017, roaming charges in the EU were abolished](http://www.bbc.com/news/business-40281013).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The Wikia webpage on prepaid mobile options in Hungary](http://prepaid-data-sim-card.wikia.com/wiki/Hungary) seems to point to the fact that, to date, the Go Napinet Netplusz L package from Magyar Telekom (formerly T-Mobile) for 1GB of data seems to be the cheapest option. Indeed, comparing data only-sims with similar data allowances yields the following ordered list (ordered from cheapest to most expensive):

#### 1. Magyar Telekom (formerly T-Mobile)

- Domino Quick - Sim card starter pack between 600 and 1,800 HUF
- Napinet Netplusz L package at 1,290`HUF` for 1GB (valid for 30 days)

Yields a minimum spend of 600`HUF` +  1,290`HUF` = 1,890`HUF`

#### 2. Vodafone

- Data-only SIM starter package for 2,990`HUF` including a 1GB weekly ticket worth of 2,490`HUF`
- Weekly ticket at 2,490`HUF` for 1GB (valid for 1 week)

Yields a minimum spend of 2,490`HUF` for 1GB of internet to be used in a week.

#### 3. Telenor

- Prepaid Hipernet Praktikum data-sim only card at 3,990`HUF` with a balance of 3,000 HUF valid for 180 days
- Data package at 2,999`HUF` for 1GB (valid for 45 days)

Yields a minimum spend of 3,990`HUF` (since you'll have just enough credit included in the starter pack to purchase the data bundle).